# Websocket $connect successful response doesn’t result in any client-side/browser success

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am using Websockets over AWS API Gateway with the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/websocket/).

I have setup a connection handler function that passes through a custom authoriser (successfully) and returns an object as such, in both a callback and return statement just to be sure:

```
const result: APIGatewayProxyResult = {
    statusCode: OK,
    headers: {
      'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol': 'graphql-ws',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: 'Connected'
};

callback(null, result);

return result;
```

The logs say it all goes smoothly, but for some reason, the browser websocket gets no response (tested in both Google Chrome or Safari) and errors with no message. It then disconnects (which triggers the $disconnect handler it seems). There seems to be 3 x `101` websocket movements from localhost, which is not the remote wss:// url I'm hitting.

For the client websocket connection, I'm using [subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.16](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws) from apollo (standard options).

Every 4th or 5th time I see the error `error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received` in the browser.

I'm sending some request headers as such, not sure if I'm meant to do anything with them on the server:

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: xxx
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: graphql-ws
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.16` was causing the issues. I switched to [RxJS webSocket lib](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) and it works fine. I assume that the Apollo lib is adding headers somewhere. There might be a better answer down the track, but for now this sorted me out.

Answer (score 3):

Generally your WebSocket event handler response is not sent back to the client. If you want to send data through the WebSocket you do it asynchronously through the [API Gateway Management API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html).

If your connection errors and disconnects unexpectedly, you have an error in either your custom authorizer or your websocket `$connect` route handler. If you see these being run in your logs, successfully, check the API Gateway log of your API. You need to enable this separately through API Gateway -> Your API -> Stages -> Your stage -> Logs/Tracing. All lower level errors in your communication are found here.